# How to hide one element inside one <div> by observing mouseover in other <div> container

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
    <div id="one-id">
        <div id="some">Info</div>
        <div id="control">
            <div id="value-1">
                <img id="image-one-id" />
                <img id="image-two-id" />
                <img id="image-three-id" />
            </div>
            <!-- this block appears after mouseover on <img id="image-x-id" />, for each image-x-id will be loaded its own values -->
            <div id="value-2">
                <div id="value-one-id"></div>
                <div id="value-two-id"></div>
                <div id="value-three-id"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="two-id">
        same logic as above
    </div>
    etc...
```

**Step 1**:`<div id="value-2">` will be shown by observing mouseover event on `<img id="image-x-id" />` and all values stay visible. `<img id="image-x-id" />` will get `class="selected"`.

**Step 2**: By mouseover `<img id="image-x-id" />` inside `<div id="two-id">` the `<div id="value-2">` inside `<div id="one-id">` must disapear and Step 1 will be repeated for `<div id="two-id">`.

I need a little help, because i'm lost in my nested divs.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/7xszH/

Comment: @Sami thanks, your example works, but [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/HS49W/4/) is more complicated, can't make it work yet..

Comment: @alex it Wud b good if u provide a fiddle

Comment: @Sami i did, see word "mine" in my answer above ;)

Comment: @alex please see my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/7xszH/37/ I used find instead of children to traverse nested childs.

Comment: @Sami thanks for your help, how can I rate your answer?

Comment: @alex I posted solution in answer. If it helped you can accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS:

```
 $('.value1').find("img").hover(function(){    
     var el = '.' + $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('.control').find(el).hide();
    $(this).closest('.control').find(el).show();
 });
```

In Css:

```
 .value1{
    background: yellow;
  }
  .value2{
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/7xszH/37/)